# Django with PostgreSQL error message: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: bigint = boolean

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to solve this error I am having in Django. Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong ? thank yo!

The error message:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: bigint = boolean
LINE 1: ... 'economy' AND "landingpage_profile"."hasArticle" = true) OR...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts
```

The model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    hasArticle       = models.BooleanField()
    ...
```

My queryset:

```
if hasArticle =="ALL":
    queryset_list = queryset_list
elif hasArticle =="ALREADY CONTRIBUTED":
    queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(hasArticle=1)
elif hasArticle =="NEVER CONTRIBUTED":
    queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(hasArticle=0)
```

I have tried this as well:

```
elif hasArticle =="ALREADY CONTRIBUTED":
    queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(hasArticle=True)
elif hasArticle =="NEVER CONTRIBUTED":
    queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(hasArticle=False)
```

A  dump of my data through API gives this:

```
    ...
    "hasArticle": false,
    "gender_guessed": "Male",
    "sfid": "001b0000003z9zeAAA",
    ...
```

Comment: Hi ,can more specify about the bug, console terminal bug

Comment: `hasArticle` is a **`BooleanField`** and you're comparing it with `string` object

Comment: I have tried (hasArticle=True) but it didnt help.